# ConcurrentModificationException overlapping two activities

Tags: android

My Main Activity have a RelativeLayout inflated with a Custom Canvas View activity.
When the user longPress on the screen, a method called "touched" inside the Main activity is called.

```
   // inside the Custom View Activity

    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
      Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() { 

        public void run() { 
            if (undoFlag) { undo(); }
                longPressed=true;
                ((ScorePadActivity)getContext()).touched();}
  };
```

Inside this method an Intent launch a second activity that overlap the main activity (without close it).

```
  // inside the main activity

public void touched() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(ScorePadActivity.this, Chords_Activity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,CREATE_CHORDS); }
```

Inside this the user make a choice over a series of buttons, when closed the result is transmitted to the (resumed) main activity.

```
 // inside the overlapped activity

    private void trasmitResult(Bitmap resultBmp2) {

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
resultBmp2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

resultIntent.putExtra("ResultChord", byteArray);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent); 
//byteArray=null;
Chords_Activity.this.finish();
}
```

This work fine on the most of the devices and Android version (from 2.3 to 4.1) but on some devices, and sometimes, opening the second activity return a ConcurrentModificationException error.

```
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:792)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:829)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:827)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:491)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1612)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:507)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:1948)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:2866)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-29 00:57:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(9209):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have made a search inside SO but all of the posts regarding ConcurrentModificationException relate about iterators or list array and, anyway,  from Google:  "An ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when a Collection is modified and an existing iterator on the Collection is used to modify the Collection as well."

But there aren't list array, hashmaps or iterators inside the code portion interested (not created from me).

I think the problem is that the main activity, opening the second overlapped activity,  enter in OnPause state, making some type of saving process and this create a conflict with the work of the overlapped activity.

Am i right?

If yes, how can syncronize the access between the two activities?

If this teory is wrong where is the problem?

Thanks